# Apache CXF DSOGI on Karaf + @Context UriInfo

Tags: dosgi

I am trying to create a RESTful web service in Karaf 4.0.8 with Apache CXF DOSGI. I am trying to add `@Context` in my implementation. How to do it?

```java
    @Component(immediate = true, property = {
    "service.exported.interfaces=*", 
    "service.exported.configs=org.apache.cxf.rs",
    "org.apache.cxf.rs.provider=com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider",
    "org.apache.cxf.rs.address=/integr" })
    public class AccountRestService implements AccountWebUserIdResource {

       @Context
       private UriInfo context;
           ...
     }
```

`UriInfo` is not getting injected properly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API Interface you need to add your `@Context`

`@GET`
`@Path("{memberid}")`
`@Produces({"application/json"})`
`MembersResource.GetMembersByMemberidResponse getMembersByMemberid(`
`@PathParam("memberid") String memberid,@QueryParam("fields") String fields,`
`@Context javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception;`